# Codesign Failed Compiling for openFrameworks

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

I continually get a codesign failure when compiling an openFrameworks (C++) program.

I found quite a few people with similar problems but the solutions did not work for me. Here is what I have done, informed by other forum entries:

- Create a new Self Signed Root certificate for Code Signing in my keychain
- Log out of and back into my keychain
- Create a new keychain, switch the default keychain, change the password of the original keychain, change the default keychain back to the original, log back into the main keychain
- Export my certificate and private key together in a `.p12` file and then import into keychain (also repeated this process with deleting the original certificate and key before importing)
- Export the certificate from Xcode (for a planned re-import) but I get "The operation could not be completed // No other information about is available about the problem" (the most unhelpful error message I've ever seen)
- "Export Apple ID and Code Signing Assets" and then import of the same (all in Xcode)
- Every combination (I think) of the Signing settings in the project

I had a developer account years ago and I wonder if somehow this is interfering with the process. I tried to access my certificates on the Apple Developer site but I don't have access to this portion of the service because my membership is expired.

This error occurs with any openFrameworks example I try as well as a new, blank sketch.

The full error message:

```
CodeSign bin/mySketchDebug.app
    cd /Users/myusername/Documents/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mySketch-etqpupvbyiamwodjeeyxogbqszyj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mySketch.build/Debug/mySketch.build/mySketchDebug.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/myusername/Documents/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/bin/mySketchDebug.app

/Users/myusername/Documents/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/bin/mySketchDebug.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/myusername/Documents/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/bin/mySketchDebug.app/Contents/Frameworks/libfmodex.dylib
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with openFrameworks <= 0.10.1 and Xcode 11+.  It is due to an unsigned libmodex library.  This is fixed in the nightly release and in future releases of oF.  Please see the following posts for references:

https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/cant-build-getting-build-failed-with-any-example-code-sign-error/33668/2

https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/cant-run-examples-in-xcode-signing-issue-with-libfmodex-dylib/33463/4

Comment: What a relief. Thank you!